# Split Json String

Tags: c#, json, string, unity-game-engine

How i can split the json string in Unity? I have a string called entry_text, which is passed by a function. When I print it out. It is

> "Atmosphere\t7\nGravity\t\nMagnetism\t\nSeismic Activity\t\nSurface\t\nTemperature\t\nWeather\t\nElement 1\t\nElement 2\t\nElement 3\t\n7",

which contains `"\t"`, and `"\n"`. So i want to split the string by `"\t"` and `"\n"`.

I used the

```
 string[] lines = entry_text.Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I also tried

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(entry_text, "\n");
```

This also does not work:

```
string[] lines = entry_text.Split(new Char[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

It seems that the split function does not take "\n" as Enter or "\t" as space from Json.

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work, exactly ? did you get wrong results ? what is your expected result ?

Comment: Does your string have a literal `\n` newline in it, or a `\` character followed by a `n` character? If the latter, have you tried `\\n` instead of `\n`?

Comment: Hi, @Selman22...i mean it did not really split it. because when i print lines.Length, it is still 1, also the lines[0] is just the full string...

Comment: Side note: I don't see any JSON in the sample... Could you please clarify why you mention JSON in the post? (I've removed some extra text from your post - feel free to revert my changes if you feel there was something important except hi/thanks text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have this as your string:

```
string entry_text = "Atmosphere\t7\nGravity\t\nMagnetism\t\nSeismic Activity\t\nSurface\t\nTemperature\t\nWeather\t\nElement 1\t\nElement 2\t\nElement 3\t\n7";
```

Remember that the `\t` and `\n` in the string are two separate characters: a `\` followed by either a `t` or `n`.

When you define:

```
string[] lines = entry_text.Split(new string[] {"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Your `{"\n"}` is being translated into a newline character, not two separate characters. For that, you will want to escape the `\` character in `\n`:

```
string[] lines = entry_text.Split(new string[] {"\\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

An alternate way of writing this is to use the `@` symbol, which means "take the literal characters in this string, instead of escaping them":

```
string[] lines = entry_text.Split(new string[] {@"\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple delimiters:

```
string[] lines = entry_text.Split('\t', '\n');
```

If you want to `Split` by new-line character you can also try this:

```
string[] lines = entry_text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```